# Powershell Script - Reinstalling Application

Tags: windows, powershell

Hoping someone can assist, I'm trying to create a powershell script that uninstalls and then reinstalls an application, the new installer is using an executable file (.exe). I've been able to get the commands to run when opening Powershell as Admin and copying the code in there but when I'm creating a PS1 File with the expectation of being able to use it across multiple machines it fails, this looks to be down to it not being ran with administrative privileges and when it is ran with Admin privileges it seems to close without running.

Current Code:

```
$title    = 'application name'
$question = 'Do you require reinstallation of application?'
$choices  = '&Yes', '&No'

$decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1)
if ($decision -eq 0) {
    Write-Host 'confirmed'
} else {
    Write-Host 'cancelled'
}

if ($decision -eq 0){
$Main = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "Name of current application installed"}
$Main.Uninstall()

Start-Process -FilePath "new exe file path" -ArgumentList "/s /v/qn"
}
```

I have tried creating a shortcut to the ".ps1" file, the initial stumble block was not being able to select 'Run as administrator' within advanced properties, to surpass this I added in target prior to path "powershell.exe" which then allowed this option to be selected, once selected I proceed to open the shortcut which opens powershell but then immediately closing it without running the code.

I have also tried creating a batch file to open powershell initially and then open powershell with administrative permissions by using the below but this results similarly to the above whereby it closes the new powershell window without running the code.

```
powershell -Noprofile -Command "& {Start-process Powershell -Argumentlist '-NoProfile -File ""Path to .PS1 file""' -verb RunAs}";
```

Hoping someone may be able to advise where I'm going wrong.

Comment: if you install application with admin rights, you have to uninstall with same rights at minimun

Comment: Hi Frenchy, yes I understand that it requires administrative privileges, the problem is getting the script to run as administrator as demonstrated above.

Comment: when you open the powershell in admin, its ok ?

Comment: Yes so when I run powershell as admin and then input the above code it works perfectly as I would expect, the problem is when saving the PS1 script as a file and then running that it doesn’t natively run as an elevated command and therefore fails the the script or not even run at all with the workarounds I’ve tried to implement.

Comment: What I usually do in this situation is create a Scheduled Task set to run with highest privileges to execute PowerShell with the Arguments being -File xxxxx.ps1 using an admin account. Then I create a shortcut to the scheduled task.

Comment: the only problem i could see is the *$Host.UI.PromptForChoiceù, could you test your file without the question asked?

Comment: @RetiredGeek, I could try that but I was hoping for something much easier, simply due to the amount of machines I'm intending to use this script for to save time for others within the Business, I'm not fussed about it requiring a UAC Prompt but it's just getting to that stage when running the script that I'm struggling to get to.

Comment: @Frenchy I've tried without using the Host ui string previously but it still comes down to Powershell not being able to run through the PS1 script due to administrative privileges required which is required on both the uninstallation and installation of the new executable/application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's closing the new shell window without running the code it might be showing an error that you don't see because the window is closed after running the script.

Try adding the "-NoExit" argument in your .cmd file, which will leave the shell open so that you can see any potential errors:

```
powershell -noexit "& ""c:\path\to\your\script.ps1"""
```